# How do you clone a sharepoint 2010 front end server and then add the clone to the farm?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, configuration

We have a SharePoint 2010 farm with one front-end server.  This server is a VMWare virtual machine.  Let's call it SERVER1.

We want to add a new front-end server to this SP farm to enable load balancing.  We have already cloned SERVER1  (named it SERVER2).

The problem is that this clone already "thinks" is it part of the farm since the only thing that has really changed is the host/computer name.  When we run the farm configuration wizard, it does not give us a chance to "add server to existing farm".

What can we  do to SERVER2 so that it thinks it is not part of the farm and could be added to the farm?

Seth

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add new servers to the farm like this. It has attributes tied to `Server1` in the database and uninstalling it will cause problems for the real `Server1`. You should roll out a new server without SP installed and install SP on it from scratch. It will automatically copy all of the necessary files from the other front-end servers that it needs and you'll be up in no time.

If you're worried about scaling out, you can always script the installation of SharePoint for future servers. It's not very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disconnect or unplug your network from the new box.
2. Run the setup program and disconnect it from the old farm.
3. Reconnect it to the network
4. Run the setup wizard to add the new box to the farm.

Note: If you cloned the box, too, you may have other domain issues if you're on a domain.

Answer (score 0):

you could basicly run the setup and remove it from the farm .. but make sure to have a valid backup of your farm config database so you can restore your databases